# SQL Server add a column constraint to limit data to -1 to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I want to constrain a SQL Server decimal column to only allow -1,0,1 as valid values.

Can you show me the SQL syntax for adding such a constraint. (I would like to know how to do it in both the CREATE TABLE statement and/or the ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT).

Or can this only be accomplished in a trigger?

Comment: This can be accomplished by a trigger, but this is the hard way. gbn gave you the solution.

Comment: alternatively, if you want to accept all possible values between -1 and +1, you could create a constraint `CHECK (bar BETWEEN -1.0 AND 1.0)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    bar int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (bar IN (-1, 0, 1))
)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE foo WITH CHECK ADD --added WITH CHECK
   CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (bar IN (-1, 0, 1)) --not needed "FOR bar"
```

Edit: thoughts...

- why constrain a decimal? Can you change it to smallint or int?
- what about NULLs? You may need to change my code around to do exactly what you want

Comment: maybe useful for MySQL searchers: "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines." from MySQL documentation, and yep it's really ignored

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [`CHECK Constraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
create table (
    x integer check (x = -1 or x = 0 or x = 1), 
    y integer
);


insert test values(5,5)
insert test values(-1, 5)
insert test values(0, 5)
insert test values(1, 5)

alter table test with nocheck add check(y = -1 or y = 0 or y = 1);
-- with no check prevents errors for illegal values already in the table
insert test values(-1, 1)
insert test values(0, -1)
insert test values(1, 0)

select * from test
```