# Data validation for a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server. I have a field in this table and its value should be between 1 and 9. How can I set this constraint to prevent invalid data entries?
Providing an error message by message box is preferable for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718256/sql-server-add-a-column-constraint-to-limit-data-to-1-to-1 this might be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Check Constraint` to restrict the data inserted into that column.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
..
field int CHECK (field between 1 and 9)
..
)
```

If you don't want to allow `NULL` then make it as `NOT NULL` column